# What's the difference between WaitForMultipleObjects and boost::asio on multiple windows::basic_handle's?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio, waitformultipleobjects

I have a list of HANDLE's, controlled by a lot of different IO devices. What would be the (performance) difference between:

1. A call to WaitForMultipleObjects on all these handles
2. async_read on boost::windows::basic_handle's around all these handles

Is WaitForMultipleObjects O(n) time complex with n the amount of handles?
You can somehow call async_read on a windows::basic_handle right? Or is that assumption wrong?
If I call run on the same IO device in multiple threads, will the handling-calls be balanced between those threads? That would be a major benefit of using asio.

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: Why is that? I have a lot of handles to wait for, and 2 ways I can do this. The fact that they're all windows handles mimics the fact they're different IO devices, hence I can use WaitForMultipleObjects if I want to. But why should I prefer one method over the other?

Comment: It is the same reason you prefer boost over Win32 the reset of the time (portability, richer interfaces)

Comment: @Pieter I meant asynchronous reads with a cross platform library versus a windows API for synchronizing objects with blocking. Comparing WaitForMultipleObjects to boost::thread library objects like conditions and semaphores is more equivalent.

Comment: On Windows boost::asio is not a wrapper around WaitForMultipleObjects nor WaitForSingleObject, it's a wrapper around IO Completion Ports. I don't know how to use the IO Completion Port native API, hence I'm asking this question using boost::asio. This is a follow up question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184658/wheres-the-balance-between-thread-amount-and-thread-block-times Rephrased my question would be: What's the difference between calling WaitForMultipleObjects, or managing calls to GetQueuedCompletionStatus from a single thread.

Comment: @Pieter: boost::asio ships with several implementations, there are wrappers for both WFMO and IOCP, controlled by #define.  IIRC, you have to use the WFMO version if you're duplicating handles.

Comment: @AJG85: WaitForMultipleObjects(Ex) handles asynchronous reads (the Windows term is OVERLAPPED).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

since it sounds like the main use you would derive from asio is the fact that it is built on top of IO completion ports (iocp for short). So, let's start with comparing iocp with `WaitForMultipleObjects()`. These two approaches are essentially the same as `select` vs. `epoll` on linux.

The main drawback of `WaitForMultipleObjects` that was solved by iocp is the inability to scale with many file descriptors. It is O(n), since for each event you receive you pass in the full array again, and internally WaitForMultipleObjects must scan the array to know which handles to trigger on.

However, this is rarely a problem because of the second drawback. `WaitForMultipleObjects()` has a limit on the max number of handles it can wait on (`MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS`). This limit is 64 objects (see winnt.h). There are ways around this limit by creating Event objects and tying multiple sockets to each event, and then wait on 64 events.

The third drawback is that there's actually a subtle "bug" in `WaitForMultipleObjects()`. It returns the index of the handle which triggered an event. This means it can only communicate a single event back to the user. This is different from `select`, which will return all file descriptors that triggered an event. `WaitForMultipleObjects` scans the handles passed in to it and return the *first* handle that has its event raised.

This means, if you are waiting on 10 very active sockets, all of which has an event on them most of the time, there will be a very heavy bias toward servicing the first socket in the list passed in to `WaitForMultipleObjects`. This can be circumvented by, every time the function returns and the event has been serviced, run it again with a timeout of 0, but this time only pass in the part of the array 1 past the event that triggered. Repeatedly until all handles has been visited, then go back to the original call with all handles and an actual timeout.

iocp solves all of these problems, and also introduces an interface for a more generic event notification, which is quite nice.

With iocp (and hence asio):

1. you don't repeat which handles you're interested in, you tell windows once, and it remembers it. This means it scales a lot better with many handles.
2. You don't have a limit of the number of handles you can wait on
3. You get every event, i.e. there's no bias towards any specific handle

I'm not sure about your assumption of using `async_read` on a custom handle. You might have to test that. If your handle refers to a socket, I would imagine it would work.

As for the threading question; yes. If you `run()` the `io_service` in multiple threads, events are dispatched to a free thread, and will scale with more threads. This is a feature of iocp, which even has a thread pool API.

In short: I believe asio or iocp would provide better performance than simply using `WaitForMultipleObjects`, but whether or not that performance will benefit you mostly depends on how many handles you have and how active they are.

Answer (score 0):

Both `WaitForSingleObject` & `WaitForMultipleObjects` are widely used functions, The `WaitForSingleObject` function is used for waiting on a single Thread synchronization object. This is signaled when the object is set to signal or the time out interval is finished. If the time interval is INFINITE, it waits infinitely.

```
DWORD WaitForSingleObject(
  HANDLE hHandle,
  DWORD  dwMilliseconds
);
```

The `WaitForMultipleObjects` is used to wait for multiple objects signaled. In the Semaphore thread synchronization object, when the counters go to zero the object is non-signaled. The Auto reset event and Mutex is non-signaled when it releases the object. The manual reset event does affect the wait functions' state.

```
DWORD WaitForMultipleObjects(
  DWORD        nCount,
  const HANDLE *lpHandles,
  BOOL         bWaitAll,
  DWORD        dwMilliseconds
);
```

If `dwMilliseconds` is `zero`, the function does not enter a wait state if the object is not signaled; it always returns immediately. If `dwMilliseconds` is `INFINITE`, the function will return only when the object is signaled.